# Numerical precision of product of probabilities (normal CDF)

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution, matlab

I'm trying to calculate $\prod_k{p_k}$ where $p_k$ are (potentially) very high probabilities of independent, zero-mean, standard normal random variables and $k>100$. However, I'm running into numerical problems using MATLAB (although the same problem occurs in Python/Scipy). Let's say $x=30$, then

```
normcdf(x)
```

returns 1, which is not precise. However, if I use `normcdf(-x)` (or `normcdf(x,'upper')`) instead, I get a value of 4.906713927148764e-198. I was hoping that I could then take 1 minus this value to get a more accurate probability. Unfortunately, the result gets rounded, as soon as I apply the subtraction:

```
>> normcdf(-x)
ans =
    4.906713927148764e-198
>> 1-(1-normcdf(-x))
ans =
     0
```

Is there any way to work around this issue?

Comment: What are the mean and variances?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay The variables are normalized to zero mean and unit-variance (I updated the question)

Comment: In what application is $1-4.9\times 10^{-198}$ a necessary level of precision???

Comment: @Arkamis the idea is that the product of the $k$ probabilities will give me $P( \cap_k \{X \le x_k\})$ which should be in the order of $1 \times 10^{-6}$

Comment: Probabilities is defined as being a value in $[0,1]$. $10^6$ makes no sense, either.

Comment: @Arkamis sorry, I forgot the negative sign...

Comment: That makes more sense. $10^{-6}$ is still practically zero for most applications, but if you need that level of precision (i.e. particle physics), then perhaps try taking the logarithm and summing.

Comment: I think that summing the logarithms is a very good idea. When you have this sum, there are quite many things you could do to appreciate the distance to $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Hi and thank you - I did consider taking the logarithm, however `log(1-normcdf(-x))` and `log(normcdf(x))` both just return 1.

Comment: @ws6079: I think you mean that they return zero. Try `log1p(-normcdf(-x))`, which, in this case, returns exactly `-normcdf(-30)`. `eps(1)` is much larger than `normcdf(-30)` so you'll never be able to subtract it in floating point.

Comment: Of course you are right, I meant zero. Thanks a lot for the `log1p` function!! I didn't know that it existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to compute such tiny probabilities, one way is to use symbolic math and/or [variable precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

For example, using the [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) function in the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html):

```
X = sym(-300);
P = normcdf(X,0,1)
P2 = vpa(P)
```

which returns

```
P =

erfc(150*2^(1/2))/2


P2 =

7.449006262775352900552391145102e-19547
```

Of course converting this result back to floating-point (`double(P2)`) results in zero as `P2` is less than [`eps(realmin)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). However, it's possible that if you do your calculations in variable precision and convert back to floating-point at the end you may be able gain a bit more accuracy. Just check to make sure that you're not wasting compute cycles.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In general, in 32-bit floating point arithmetic, $$1+\epsilon = 1,$$

where $|\epsilon| < |\epsilon_{\textrm{mach}}|$, the right-hand side being the machine epsilon.

I also question the need to compute a probability to 198 decimal places. There are about $10^{80}$ atoms in the universe. I cannot possibly imagine the need to compute probabilities so precisely that they could be used to predict something at the atomic level in two standard and one somewhat smallish universe.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the joint probability of independent events, each one of which has a high probability of occurring - well specifically I'm interested in the complement of this probability. I would be grateful for any suggestions for alternative approaches.